# Video editing web app with requirements

Tags: gratis, web-apps, video-editing

I'm looking for video editing software with the following requirements:

- Web based (compatible with a ChromeBook)
- Gratis
- Easy to use (doesn't require extensive research and learning for simple edits)
- Can take video
- Modify the video to display in slow motion
- Add overlays
- Add voiceovers
- Splice together video
- Import GIF files

A feature that isn't a requirement but wanted is:

- Doesn't add a watermark

Background: I'd like to make a good video explaining quantum computing. I have plenty of ideas for how to make the video, but it's going to involve some Mathematica animations that I'll export as gif files, and I'm going to have to do a voiceover on those files to explain what's happening. I'll also need to take some video and edit it in the ways described above. If the editing program also has a way to enhance it, that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [WeVideo](https://www.wevideo.com/). While it does have a pesky watermark, there are online watermark removers, and so it was a pretty good option. You can do various overlays to add text or whatever, add voiceovers and audio files of all types, it is web based, free, and easy to use, and it can take in and export videos of all different file types. While I'm not sure how to make it modify a video just yet, it shouldn't be too hard to do.

So, in the end, this worked perfectly for what I was doing.